# Square Bracket use in original quote

Tags: punctuation, quotations

When using an original quote in a document that already includes [] square brackets, how would that be set apart showing that it is the original quote if it already contains the square brackets. What punctuation should be used?

Comment: No additional punctuation is needed. You can optionally add  (Brackets in the original.) after the quotation if you need to for clarity.

Comment: After the quote, can you add '[sic]' to indicate the quote is exactly as shown?

Comment: @Yosef Baskin That is reserved for pointing out original **errors** (or unconventialities). See [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sic).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth if [sic] is for unconventialities, surely it could be appropriate since square brackets in quotations is unconventional?

Comment: @marcellothearcane No. You would be flagging an _improper_ use of square brackets with [sic], rather than an 'already-present' one. The use of square brackets in the document OP is quoting may well be conventional.